# Can't connect to public (unsecured) wifi networks (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and I can't connect specifically to public Wifi. The hardware and driver work fine because I can connect to my personal pocket wifi. But when I try to switch to public wifi, for example the wifi in macdonald free wifi or the wifi in the hotel, I can't not connect to those public wifi. Those public wifi also set up fine because I can connect them with my ipad. When I try to connect to public wifi, it shows "Active connection removed before it was initialized" and just back to the status of no wifi connection.

Any hint about what may be happening?

The output of `ifconfig`:

```
ens5f5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5b:39:83:b9:28  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:34 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:142052 (142.0 KB)  TX bytes:142052 (142.0 KB)

wls1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:4b:d6:f8:47:a5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e8db:4062:360c:59b4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37646 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:47101326 (47.1 MB)  TX bytes:2898127 (2.8 MB)
```

The output of `iwconfig`:

```
ens5f5    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wls1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"00_MCD-FREE-WIFI"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 12:09:B4:69:4B:2A   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:38   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: This may sound completely weird but I fixed a similar problem a while ago with a friends notebook by opening it and reattach the loose antenna cable of the wifi card. You did some service work on your hardware lately?

Comment: @FredFoo it is unlikely to be a hardware issue since ShihYen is able to connect to personel pocket wifi.

Comment: @Dhaval You would think so, but that is the funny thing about a loose cable: it works and not :) Simply because of the weak nature of the wifi signal. Sometimes the signal power sufficient, even without the cable, sometimes its not.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` (while logged associate with such a network)? This kind of public networks often have "landing pages" that require you to agree to something before you can use the network. This is achieved by having the local DNS server redirect you to said landing page upon your first DNS request. If configured DNS manually and not automatically (through DHCP), this technique doesn't work and all your requests are blocked. So, please set DNS back to automatic and try again.

Comment: Thank you  guys so much. It was the problem that local DNS server doesn't direct me to the landing page. I set up my IP manually and everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case I suggest to set up your IP manually, following these steps:

```
sudo iwconfig [INTERFACE] mode managed key open
sudo iwconfig [INTERFACE] essid [ESSID]
```

Now set your IP address:

```
sudo ifconfig [INTERFACE] [IP ADDRESS] netmask [SUBNETMASK]
```

Then add your IP of router as default gateway:

```
sudo route add default gw [ROUTER GATEWAY]
```

Finally, configure DNS:

```
sudo echo nameserver [DNS]  >>  /etc/resolve.conf
```

Comment: Thanks really a lot. This works absolutely fine with my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu budgie 20.04.1. I could connect to my college's wifi but couldn't access the authentication page as it wouldn't pop up. Even pasting the login page URL from another device didn't work. entering a URL such as https://www.google.com was rejected instead of redirecting to the login page. What worked for me was entering 1.1.1.1. I tried this because things like updates still worked even though I was not logged into the network. I had hoped that I could just use my own DNS and drive on. Instead, I was redirected to the login page that I couldn't access any other way. either way, problem solved. Hope this helps.